# What's the best way to go about implementing hashtag functionality in EF Core/Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to implement hasthags into an application. I've configured the database already and even have a layout for how I'd like the form to look, however I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I want to do with Razor pages. I have the below classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    public IList<PersonTag> PersonTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag 
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public IList<PersonTag> PersonTags { get; set; }
}

public class PersonTag
{
    public int PersonTagId { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

And would like the form to look like this, where you see this input while editing a `Person`. You'd add a new hashtag by typing in the input box--hitting enter there (or pressing a button--not pictured) would create the tag in the `Tag` table and also create a new `PersonTag` relationship with the `Person` being edited, which would be saved on form submission. I guess the `Tag` could also get created on form submission if that's simpler. Clicking the "x" on one of the tags should also remove the PersonTag relationship

[image]

Is this something that's possible with razor pages? To this point I've only ever done simpler inputs (either single values or select lists), but in this case I need the user to have the option to enter free text multiple times. What kind of input would I need for these? Or would I need to do entirely special handling to pull the data on form submit, and just populate the tags with Javascript when the user adds them?

Comment: I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which I think might have one potential way I could handle this. I'm going to try to adding a string[] parameter to the OnPostAsync method and then use the name property on the tag buttons, which I'll set up as disabled (maybe hidden?) inputs. Then I'd need to use javascript to handle adding/removing inputs on the form. Still not sure if this is the right approach but seems like a potential solution that I'll at least try

Comment: You can do it as you said, it is a feasible method. But I think it is better to depend on which JQuery tag plugins you are used to display the tags. Because, they might using different data type to store the tags, such as a string or a string Array (for example: "#TestTag,#AntherTag" or ["#TestTag","#AntherTag"]). And, on the view page, when add new tags, I think it is better not to insert it into database, because user might cancle this action, you could store it on client side, then, when click the submit button, you could check if the tag exist or not, then add the tags into database.

Comment: You could search "JQuery input tags plugin" using Google or Bing, then selected one of them and check the document to use it. Besides, you could refer to [this link](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/38893873/saving-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-core) to save many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core